# python convert emoji to HTML decimal

Tags: python, django, emoji

I have a django application that consumes the twitter public API.

The tweets the application received contains some emojis and I want to convert it into HTML decimal equivalent.

Searching for `python emoji` I found two libraries (`emoji_unicode`, `pyemoji`).

I am using the two libraries as following to get the decimal value of the emoji included in tweet body;

```
import emoji_unicode, pyemoji
def emoji_callback(e):
    t = pyemoji.encode(e.unicode).replace('\\u','')
    return "&#%s;" % str(int(t, 16))
emoji_unicode.replace(u'Time to ⛽ ',emoji_callback)
```

The previous example works fine but for some other emojis it did not work and it throws an `invalid literal for int() with base 16` exception. For example the below code does not work.

```
emoji_unicode.replace(u'Time to ',call)
```

### Questions

1- Is there a simpler way to get the HTML decimal of the emoji in the tweet body instead of what is implemented here?

2- If no, how could I solve that exception and get the code working for all emojis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could probably help :)

```
def emoji_calback(e):
    '&#x{0};'.format(e.unicode.encode('unicode_escape').decode('utf8').lstrip('\\U0u'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
pyemoji.entities('Hey ')
```

This returns a unicode `string` which contains the `HTML` decimal code of the emoji.
It returns a unicode string like this:

```
u'Hey &#128512;'
```